# Bit wise and operation on list and convert value to comma separated string

Tags: c#, list, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, bitwise-operators

I have a list which returns an ID, Type and value. The IDs are stored as power of 2. Sample data below

```
var _data = await _context.clubs.Where(x => x.Type == "NewTown").ToListAsync();
```

| ID | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NewTown | Test1 |
| 2 | NewTown | Test2 |
| 4 | NewTown | Test3 |

I have a view model which stores IDs from this table by adding them like if I select first and third it will save 5 similarly if I select first and second it will save 3.

These values will be saved in a different table where I can't store the Ids as comma separated values because it would eventually b sent as a token and if I have many fields the token would exceed the length that's why I'm saving the sum of the Ids.

Now what I want to do is while displaying these values I want to show Test1 , Test3 if 5 is saved.
Now I know if I do a bit wise and operation with the array and the selected value it will give me the values like this example below.

```
var savedVal= 5;
var testArray = new int[] {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
testArray .Select(x => new { savedVal= x, Enabled = ((savedVal & x) > 0) }).Dump();
```

| savedVal | Enabled |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | False |
| 4 | True |
| 8 | False |
| 16 | False |
| 32 | False |
| 64 | False |
| 128 | False |

This will give me enabled "true" for the values that were selected.

Now what I want to know is how can I achieve this for my list scenario where I have 3 fields in the list and I want to have the values of enabled ones as a comma-separated string like "Test1, Test3" for the example I shared.

Comment: So you just want a comma separated list of values as a string? Or you want this comma separated list as a string value for all objects in the list?

Comment: Comma separated string for the values that are selected like If i select 1st and 2nd value, the sum saved would be 3 so the comma separated string I would need would be "Test1, Test2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of Linq: `Join`, `Where`, `Select`, `ToArray`, with `String.Join` to produce a list of Test Values from the DBContext by joining your returned list of `savedVals` where `Enabled = true`

```
//a test object to simulate your DBContext
var testdbcontext = new List<dynamic> 
{ 
    new { Id = 1, Type = "NewTown", Value = "Test1" }, 
    new { Id = 2, Type = "NewTown", Value = "Test2" }, 
    new { Id = 4, Type = "NewTown", Value = "Test3" }
};

var savedVal= 5;
var testArray = new int[] {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", 
    testdbcontext
   .Join(testArray.Select(x => new { savedVal= x, Enabled = ((savedVal & x) > 0) })
   .Where(b => b.Enabled)
   .Select(c => c.savedVal),
                a => a.Id,
                b => b,
                (a, b) => new string (a.Value)).ToArray()));
```

**Prints:**

```
//Test1,Test3
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is definitely correct, buy might be a bit confusing/too complex for beginners.
You literally only missed String.Join method to achieve your goal. My version of code to solve you issue is:

```
...(your code)

var _data = await _context
    .clubs
    .Where(x => x.Type == "NewTown")
    .Where (x => (savedVal & x) > 0)
    .ToListAsync();

resultString = String.Join(',', _data.Select(x => x.Value));
```